# Validation for input field name in vue 2

Tags: vue.js, validation, vuejs2

I have a input field:

```
<Fieldset>
                <label for="name" slot="label" class="label">Name</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input id="name" v-model="name" class="form-control"  :class="{ 'is-invalid': isNameInvalid }"/>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback" v-if="isNameInvalid">
                        Please enter a valid name.
                    </div>
                </div>
 </Fieldset>
```

And I am trying to add this validation. So when the input field is empty and when the form is submitted, invalid-feedback element should be shown. But if the user types more, the element shouldnt be shown. Basic validation but I couldnt apply. Here is what I am doing:

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            name: ''
            isNameInvalid: true,
        };
    },
    methods: {
        submitForm() {
            if (!this.isNameInvalid) {
                //submit form and clean form
            }
        },
        validateName() {
            this.isNameInvalid = this.name === '';
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: I think the method validateName() is never called; you can just add   @input="validateName" :    `<div class="input-group">
      <input
        id="name"
        v-model="name"
        @input="validateName"
        class="form-control"
        :class="{ 'is-invalid': isNameInvalid }"
      />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invoke `validateName` when the input value changes and when the form is submitted.

Update your HTML:

```
<input id="name" v-model="name" class="form-control"  :class="{ 'is-invalid': isNameInvalid }" @input="validateName"/>
```

and your vue component:

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            name: '',
            isNameInvalid: false,
        };
    },
    methods: {
        submitForm() {
            this.validateName();
            if (!this.isNameInvalid) {
                //submit form
            }
        },
        validateName() {
            this.isNameInvalid = this.name.trim() === '';
        },
    },
}
```

This will trigger validateName on every input change and form submission, checking if the name field is empty.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways, I would suggest to use watch.

Already defined data `name` property and `v-model` automatically update `name`. It would be better if we add `watch` to `name` and trigger/show invalid message.

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            name: '',
            isNameInvalid: false,
        };
    },
    watch: {
        name: {
           immediate: true,
           handler(value) {
               validateName();
           }
        }
    }
    methods: {
        submitForm() {
            this.validateName();
            if (!this.isNameInvalid) {
                //submit form
            }
        },
        validateName() {
            this.isNameInvalid = this.name.trim() === '';
        },
    },
}
```

Template will be same as you used.